# Windows10 USB Transfer mode

Tags: windows, usb

Will USB communication in Windows 10 be done in Bulk mode?

I'm in the process of selecting a PC and would like to know how to transfer Windows 10 to other devices for USB communication.
There are four transfer methods for USB communication, Control, Interrupt, Bulk, and Isochronous, and which one is used depends on the host.
I'm hoping to use the Bulk method of communication because I don't want USB communication without retransmission.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and which one is used depends on the host

Yes and no. The host must use the method appropriate for a device, and the device has endpoint descriptors which define whether an endpoint is bulk,interrupt or isochronous.

Note that common devices have specific endpoint type requirements: Mass storage use bulk while HID devices (e.g. mice or keyboards) use interrupt ep.